# How to do a x-days grouped sum in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I have the following table,
that shows how many items from different units entered the inventory, in different dates.

```
ID    Date       Unit   Quantity 
---------------------------------
1    2017-08-01  A_red      05
2    2017-08-13  A_red      10
3    2017-09-20  A_red      20
4    2017-09-22  A_red      40
5    2017-10-05  A_red      40
6    2017-10-25  A_red      30
7    2017-10-24  A_blue     60
```

The problem is: entries within a time interval of 30 days of the same unit should be grouped.
So I want the following result:

```
ID    Date      Unit   Quantity fst_entry30 Quantity30  
-----------------------------------------------------
1   2017-08-01  A_red     05       T          15
2   2017-08-13  A_red     10       F          15
3   2017-09-20  A_red     20       T          100
4   2017-09-22  A_red     40       F          100
5   2017-10-05  A_red     40       F          100
6   2017-10-25  A_red     30       T          30
7   2017-10-24  A_blue    60       T          60
```

where fst_entry30 is a flag that points if the entry was the first, of this unit, in the last 30 days.   Note that if i have a different unit (A_blue instead of A_red), it won't be grouped.
And quantity30 is the grouped sum of quantity.
For example, between 5 october and 20 september there is less than 30 days, so it was grouped.

Remembering that Redshift does not allow recursive common table expressions.
I already tried self-joins, but that turned out to be cumbersome.

Comment: do you have a dates table?

Comment: Yes, I do @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: In future Redshift uses SQL suited to Postgres EXCEPT for these: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use `lag()` to define the groups:

```
select t.*,
       (case when date >= lag(date) over (partition by unit order by date) + interval '30 day'
             then 0 else 1
        end) as grp_start
from t;
```

Then you can do a cumulative sum to assign a number to the group . . . and finally add them up using a window function:

```
select t.*, sum(quantity) over (partition by unit, grp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(grp_start) over (partition by unit order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when date >= lag(date) over (partition by unit order by date) + interval '30 day'
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as grp_start
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
```

Comment: Thank you, almost solved the problem, but such query would generate a false result for the id = 6. Because it's comparing 25 october with 5 october (last preceding row), when it should compare with 20th september (row where the second partition started).